# What does it mean "Stale mailbox lock file detected, will override in 0 seconds"?

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, imap, dovecot

I've implemented javax.mail.event.StoreListener for any of Store where I'm connected 24h

Today i've received for the first time this notice:

*Notice $my account$: Stale mailbox lock file detected, will override in 0 seconds*

I have never seen it before, but I suspect that it is some source of problems because in that account, after having received that notice, I lost some messages, that is javamail listener has not been notified for next incoming messages.

Thanks

Searching for the message I received took me to this Mail Server which I don't know https://www.dovecot.org/

Answer (score 1):

Some legacy Unix mail delivery programs use a lock file to prevent concurrent write access to a user's mailbox. If the program holding the lock crashes, the lock file will remain in place, preventing others from obtaining the lock. To solve this, some clients will remove the lock file if they determine that it is too old, and/or not held by a live process.

Without seeing your code and probably the state of several processes when this happened, we can't really tell you anything more.

Comment: Thx, nevertheless I have sent no message before receiving that notice.

May I ask you in this context what do you mean for "client", that is am I a client which connects to a Mail Server to download messages? I suppose yes.
And, "program holding the lock" would be the Mail Server I connect to?

Comment: Without more information, there is no way to know whether the server or another client is attempting to access the mailbox at the same time. The client/server model in this context assumes you have a server which receives messages from the outside world into the mailbox, and one or more clients which read these messages from that location, and want to mark them as e.g. read or deleted, or flagged etc. You also cannot know whether a client connected and requested write permission just in case, and never actually wrote anything. The server hopefully has logs you can examine.

Answer (score 1):

The message `Stale mailbox lock file detected, will override in 0 seconds` suggests a possible problem at the mail server. The *mailbox lock file* it refers to is used for access control between the *Mail Transfer Agent* (MTA for short; the software that listens for SMTP connections and delivers incoming email to users' mailboxes) and the *Mail User Agent* (MUA for short; the software that allows the users' mail clients to access the mailboxes to read/classify/delete email).

In your case, the MUA is probably an IMAP or POP server, and *mail client* is your application.

The lock file is one of the most classic ways to ensure the MTA will not deliver new mail as the MUA is e.g. in the middle of deleting an old message, or vice versa. If two programs make modifications to the mailbox contents simultaneously without coordination, they could corrupt the contents of the mailbox and/or cause mail to be lost.

The lock file is supposed to contain the process ID (PID) of the process that created the lock file, and so any program that sees the lock file should be able to read it and see if that process still exists; if not, the lock file can be assumed stale and replaced.

But this only works on systems where the MTA and MUA are on the same server and share the same PID space. In large environments, there might be one server dedicated to be just the MTA, and one or more servers as MUAs, and the mailboxes shared between them with NFS or similar; in such an environment, overriding a lock file cannot be done safely, as the process that owns the lock file might be on a different server.

Likewise, if a MTA or MUA has been implemented using container technology, it might be isolated into its own PID namespace and won't be able to see the other process accessing the mailbox, which would cause it to mis-detect the mailbox lock file as stale when it actually isn't, and cause mail to be lost or corrupted.

Even in an environment where the MTA and MUA are on the same server and within the same PID space, the message would indicate that **a process that was writing to the mailbox file has crashed.** And that should never happen.

You should contact the administrators of the mail server (specifically the IMAP/POP server) you're using, and report the problem to them.